# Accessing express session cookies in react

Tags: reactjs, express, express-session

Is there any way to just access the cookies generated from express-session in react?
I have generated an express-session cookie as follows

```
app.use(
session({
  key: "userId",
  secret: "subscribe",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
  },
}) );
```

Now if I'm trying to access the cookies from react using universal-cookie or js-cookie libraries I cannot access the cookie.

PS: In react file I have added

```
Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and in backend file I have configured cors as

```
app.use(cors({
origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
methods: ["GET", "POST"],
credentials: true, }));
```

but it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use **express-session**, the only cookie sent to frontend is **connect.sid**. By default, it is httpOnly, this way you cannot access it in React. To achieve it, you need to change httpOnly config to false.

```
app.use(
  session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "subscribe",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
      httpOnly: false,
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Can you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253135/unable-to-set-cookie-from-express-js-session-in-brave-firefox-etc-browsers-and