# Unable to set cookie from Express JS session in brave, firefox, etc browsers and in chrome, and edge, cookie isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, express, session, cross-browser, express-session

I have created a website in which **I'm facing three issues**:

My backend Express JS code:

**index.js** file

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
require("dotenv").config();

// App initialization
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Database connection
require("./db/index").connect();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());

// CORS
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, "http://localhost:3000"],
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
        credentials: true,
    })
);

// Session
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: !process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        saveUninitialized: !process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15,
            sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        },
    })
);

if (app.get("env") === "production") {
    app.set("trust proxy", 1); //necessary to set up a cookie in production
}

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./config/passportConfig")(passport);

// Routes

app.use("/", (_req, res) => {
    res.send("<h1>Welcome to the API :)</h1>");
});

// Listen on port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

In the **front end (React JS)**, I'm calling API using Axios like below:

**axios.js** file

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const customAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://my-expense-tracker-backend.herokuapp.com",
  timeout: 10000,
});

const requestHandler = (request) => request;

const responseHandler = (response) => {
  return response;
};

const errorHandler = (error) => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) window.location = "/login";
  else if (error.response.status === 0) alert("Server is not running");
  return Promise.reject(error);
};

customAxios.interceptors.request.use(
   (request) => requestHandler(request),
   (error) => errorHandler(error)
);

customAxios.interceptors.response.use(
   (response) => responseHandler(response),
   (error) => errorHandler(error)
);

export default customAxios;
```

**Issues:**

1. Unable to set cookies in some browsers like brave, firefox. But cookies are working fine in chrome and edge browser.
2. When I'm logging in to chrome, edge browser, I'm unable to see any cookie but the app is working
   fine

   [image: chromebrowser example]
3. When I'm logging in the first time, it's working fine in chrome, and the edge browser, but when I'm trying to log in again after 3 to 4 hours, I'm unable to log in automatically even after setting the cookie for 15 days, I have to login again.

Can someone help with the above problems?

[Live Website](https://expense-tracker-frontend.vercel.app/)

[Frontend Github link](https://github.com/deep1358/Expense-Tracker-Frontend)

[Backend Github link](https://github.com/deep1358/Expense-Tracker-Backend)

Answer (score 0):

For number 1, I guess there is a bit of difference in browsers behaviour while setting sameSite flag. Got this [From here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)

Note: Standards related to the Cookie SameSite attribute recently changed such that:

> The cookie-sending behavior if SameSite is not specified is SameSite=Lax. Previously the default was that cookies were sent for all requests.
> Cookies with SameSite=None must now also specify the Secure attribute (they require a secure context/HTTPS).
> Cookies from the same domain are no longer considered to be from the same site if sent using a different scheme (http: or https:).

For number 2, probably the origin(url) of the cookie(may be from a backend that's on a different url) is different in this case may be from localhost :3000, remember the cookie will be listed from the origin...so if u crank open a new tab and open up the cookies origin url(may be your back end service) and check cookies u should see the cookie there..

Comment: Hi Amasa, thanks for your reply. For the 1st question, I got the concept of the Same site and Secure, and I know the behavior of the browser. But How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. Please help me, how did you solve it?  @DeepShah

Comment: @Paulliano For the 1st question, that's the browser's default behavior, so the only way is to set cookies from the front end. For the 2nd question, still not sure what's the issue. And for the 3rd question, I am using Heroku free tier for hosting, so what happens is that Heroku dynos go to sleep after 25-30 mins of inactivity, so it'll destroy the express session while going to sleep, so whenever we hit API, it'll wake up and create session again.

Comment: My app was working fine, I am able to login on chrome, brave, and firefox( on my laptop and andriod ). But am not able to login on ios device and safari browser. Pls do you have any clue why this is happening? @DeepShah

Comment: No idea about the ios platform.

Comment: @DeepShah were you able to unblock this issue with brave? i have it working fine on chrome but cookie session is not set with brave

Comment: @caffeinescript it's not possible to set cookie from third party website in brave. And chrome will stop this feature soon.